# Convert Latitude and Longitude Values (Decimals) to Double

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, double, cordova-plugins

I am currently using this plugin 
https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder
in a cordova/ionic app and on iOS I am getting an error stating that I need to provide the coordinates as double.

The documentation clearly states this however since I am using https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/ to get the latitude and longitude on ios these are being returned in decimals and quite long and not sure how to do this in javascript. I have been searching here ie: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=double+latitude+and+longitude but none of those answers are clear or in javascript / angularjs. Here is the code of how I get the coordinates.

```
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function (position) {
    var lat  = position.coords.latitude
    var long = position.coords.longitude
```

Thanks

Comment: Are *lat* and *long* strings? Perhaps you just need `+position.coords.latitude` to coerce the value to Number. Javascript doesn't have float, integer, etc. types, it just has [*Number*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function (position) { 
   var lat  = position.coords.latitude
   var long = position.coords.longitude
 });
```

> in above code it can get lat long in string format that reason it can give you error 
>   
>   
> follwing code fix it

```
 $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function (position) { 
   var lat  = position.coords.latitude
   var long = position.coords.longitude
   var latDouble  = parseFloat(lat);
   var longDouble = parseFloat(long);
 });
```

how to check is type right or not??

> print in console.log();
> if string then print like "21.4564879" 
> if double then directly display 21.4564879